# Unity3d: Box collider attached to animated FBX models through scripts at run-time have wrong dimension

Tags: unity, bounding-boxes, bounding-spheres

I have several scripts attached to static and non static models of my scene. 
All models are instantiated at run-time (and must be instantiated at run-time because I'm procedural building the scene).

I'd like to add a `BoxCollider` or `SphereCollider` to my `FBX` models at runtime.

With non animated models it works simply requiring `BoxCollider` component from the script attached to my `GameObject`. `BoxCollider` is created of the right dimension.
Something like:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider))]
public class AScript: MonoBehavior
{

}
```

If I do the same thing with animated models, `BoxCollider` are created of the wrong dimension. 
For example if attach the script above to penelopeFBX model of the standard asset, `BoxCollider` is created smaller than the mesh itself.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Bounds to generate the box collider? You use something like this in runtime:

```
   Bounds mapBounds = new Bounds (transform.position, Vector3.one);
      foreach(Transform child in this.transform) {
        mapBounds.Encapsulate(child.gameObject.renderer.bounds);
   }
```

And then Add a BoxCollider and adjust according to those bounds.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know about that. I'll try your solution as soon as possible.

Comment: sorry..It doesn't work. with rig datas inside the animated models, even with your method the size of mapBounds is wrong. It seems that rig controls point are included while calculating bounds.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Have your tried asking this in [unity answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/)? You might have better luck asking such a specific question there.